# Accessing JSON data with C#

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, json.net

I am having a heck of a time accessing the numeric distance "value" from the below JSON return. I'm Using the JSON.NET 3.5 library. The Program dies with:

Compiler Error Message: CS0119: 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Elements(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Xml.Linq.XName)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Source Error:

```
Line 64: GeoElements Elements =     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoElements>geoResponse.ToString());
Line 65: 
Line 66: count2 = geoResponse.Elements.Length;
Line 67: for (int j = 0; j < count2; j++)
Line 68: {
```

Here is the JSON return followed by the C# codebehind:

```
 {
    "destination_addresses" : [ "3095 E Patrick Ln, Las Vegas, NV 89120, USA" ],
    "origin_addresses" : [ "Vegas @ Advanced Tech Academy (E), Las Vegas, NV 89106, USA" ],
    "rows" : [
       {
          "elements" : [
             {
                "distance" : {
                   "text" : "13.4 mi",
                   "value" : 21573
                },
                "duration" : {
                   "text" : "24 mins",
                   "value" : 1429
                },
                "status" : "OK"
             }
          ]
       }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
 }
```

---

```
            public partial class maproute : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 

    public class GeoDistance
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    public class GeoElements
    {
        public GeoDistance distance { get; set; }
    }

    public class GeoResult        
    {
        public GeoElements[] Elements { get; set; }             
    }         
    public class GeoResponse       
    {            
        public string Status { get; set; }           
        public GeoResult[] Rows { get; set; }
    } 


    public int parseDistance(string stream)
    {
        //process response file
        GeoResponse geoResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoResponse>(stream);
        int dist = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        try
        {
        if (geoResponse.Status == "OK")
        {
            count = geoResponse.Rows.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                GeoElements Elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoElements>(geoResponse.ToString());

                count2 = geoResponse.Rows[i].Elements.Length;
                for (int j = 0; j < count2; j++)
                {
                    dist = geoResponse.Rows[i].Elements[j].distance.value;

                    //dist = dist/1609.3;  
                } 

                //dist = dist/1609.3;  
            }   

        }  

            //    dist = 4;  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("DEBUG: ");
            Response.Write("Status: " + geoResponse.Status);
            Response.Write("</br>");
            Response.Write("Results: " + geoResponse.Rows.Length);
            Response.Write("</br>");                
        }
        return dist;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements is array in JSON, but single value in your classes, making it array should work:

```
public GeoElements[] elements { get; set; }
```

Comment: That cleared one error and left me with:     CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'distance' and no extension method 'distance' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

Source Error:   

 

Line 61:                 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
Line 62:                 {
Line 63:                     dist = geoResponse.Rows[i].elements.distance.value;
Line 64:                     //dist = dist/1609.3;  
Line 65:                 }

Comment: Maybe it should be List<GeoElements>, not an array... I don't have JSON.net setup to try it out...

Answer (score 1):

> The deserialized type must be an array or implement a collection interface like IEnumerable, ICollection or IList.

It does exactly what it says on the tin: You need an array of `GeoElements` to deserialize your JSON.
Your `GeoElement` in your code is a single value. It is an array in your json. So either inherit the `IList/ICollection` interface in your `GeoElement` class, or declare your GeoElement as an array of GeoElements

```
class GeoElement : ICollection { ... }
```

or

```
GeoElement[] elements = JSONConverter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: I can't wrap my head around the ICollection. I added a nested loop to grab the elements array contents, but that is erroring out. I believe it is because I am not referencing the elements array correctly in relation to the rows array, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. I will say that LINQ and JSON structures are completely new to me

Comment: Found the issue finally. My Classes were defined wrong. Found http://json2csharp.com/  all I needed to do was drop the JSON data I was getting from Google in to the box and It generated the proper class Structure for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue finally. My Classes were defined wrong. Found http://json2csharp.com/ all I needed to do was drop the JSON data I was getting from Google in to the box and It generated the proper class Structure for me.